# Compare Across Arrays by Index in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I'm looking to compare values of several arrays by index.

For example, if I have

```
a = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
b = [2, 2, 5, 5, 5, 2]
c = [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
```

I'd like to be able to determine that index 2 of array b is out of range of a and c.

Even more so, I'd like it to output the index of the third value which is out of range in a row.

So far, I have something like:

```
av = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
sd = [0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1, 0.1]

x = 1.1

counter = 0
for index, value in enumerate(np.sum([av,sd], axis=0)):
    if value > x:
        counter += 1
    else: 
        counter = 0   
    if counter >= 3:
        print "misbehaving channels"
        print(index, value)
        break
```

which will output (4, 1.2), telling me the index after it has been >x for 3 elements in a row, and the value at that index.

However, as you can see, this doesn't compare across arrays, just where x = 1.1

So, going back to the original example, ideally, the output would be something like (4, 5), where the index is 4, value is 5.

Thanks, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What if there are multiple out of range item within `b` or even duplicate for example if there are multiple range of 5 in `b`? like `b = [2, 2, 5, 5, 5, 2, 4, 4, 5, 5, 1, 1]`

Comment: I'm only concerned about the first time it is out of range for 3 elements in a a row! Which is why I placed the "break" at the end of that loop, so for your example, the output would still be (4, 5)

Comment: `a, b, c` are lists, not arrays. `[]` denote a list in Python. Why should index 2 of `b` be out of range? The indexes of `a, b, c` all have a range of 0 to 5. Do you mean the range of the values stored in `a, b, c`?

Comment: And by "out of range of a and c", you mean being greater than the max. of a and c combined or being greater than elementwise summation of `a` and `c`?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a vectorized way using [`np.convolve`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.convolve.html) -

```
# Get the index of first such occurance
idx = np.where(np.convolve(b>(a+c),[1]*3)>=3)[0][0]

# Index into b and get the tuple of index and value
out = (idx, b[idx])
```

Sample run -

```
In [265]: a = np.array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
     ...: b = np.array([2, 2, 5, 5, 5, 2])
     ...: c = np.array([3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3])
     ...: 

In [266]: idx = np.where(np.convolve(b>(a+c),[1]*3)>=3)[0][0]

In [267]: (idx, b[idx])
Out[267]: (4, 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
a = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
b = [2, 2, 5, 5, 5, 2]
c = [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]

a = np.array(a)
b = np.array(b)
c = np.array(c)

out_of_range = (b < a)|(b > c) # array([False, False,  True,  True,  True, False], dtype=bool)

third_in_a_row = [i for i in xrange(2, len(a)) if out_of_range[i] and out_of_range[i-1] and out_of_range[i-2]] # [4]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution using `groupby` from `itertools` which groups the in-range and out-of-range sequence consecutively and then we can loop through the iterator, and check if the group is out of range and size is larger than or equal to `3`, if it is, add 3 to the index, find the value correspondingly and stop, otherwise keep moving forward until the sequence is found. If nothing is found, the value would be none and index be -1:

```
from itertools import groupby
index = -1
value = None
for k, g in groupby(y < min(x, z) or y > max(x, z) for x, y, z in zip(a, b, c)):
    grp_size = len(list(g))
    if k and grp_size >= 3:
        index += 3
        value = b[index]
        break
    else:
        index += grp_size

if value is not None:          
    print((index, value))  
# (4, 5)
```